# Taking the limits of Probabilities

Tags: linear-algebra, probability

I am trying to understand the following point in Continuous Time Markov Chains (CTMC)

**A) Basic Review of Continuous Time Markov Chains:**

In the case of a **Continuous Time Markov Chain**, we define its "Rate Matrix" as the instantaneous rate of transitioning between any two states:

$$
Q_{ij} = 
\begin{bmatrix}
q_{11} & q_{12} & \cdots & q_{1m} \\
q_{21} & q_{22} & \cdots & q_{2m} \\
\vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
q_{m1} & q_{m2} & \cdots & q_{mm}
\end{bmatrix}
$$
$$q_{ii} = -\sum_{\substack{j=1 \\ j \neq i}}^{m} q_{ij}$$

E.g. In a 3 state Markov Chain, $q_{11} = - (q_{12} + q_{13})$

We use the Kolmogorov Forward Equations to "recover" the time-dependent probability transition matrix (I like to think of $q_{ij}$ as the "average" transition rate in some very small amount of time from state i to state j ... across all possible times):

$$
\lim_{{t \to 0}} \frac{{P_{ij}(t)}}{t} = 
\begin{cases} 
q_i & \text{if } i = j \\
q_{ij} & \text{if } i \neq j 
\end{cases}
$$

$$\frac{dP(t)}{dt} = P(t)Q$$
$$P(t) = e^{tQ}$$
$$\exp(Qt) = I + Qt + \frac{1}{2!} Q^2t^2 + \frac{1}{3!} Q^3t^3 + \ldots$$

where:

- P(t) is the matrix of transition probabilities at time t : **This tells us - in some time "t", what is the probability of transitioning from state = i to state = j ?**
- Q is the transition rate matrix
- Note that $P(t) = e^{tQ}$ has to be numerically approximated
- Note that the "continuous" part of the CTMC can NOT directly be used to find out what state the chain will go to next [e.g. in 0.01 seconds, $P_{ij}(0.01)$ - the chain could go from state i to state j ... but also make an intermediate trip to state k at 0.005 seconds i.e. (i,k) and then go to j 0.005 seconds later i.e. (k,j) ]
- The continuous part of the CTMC can NOT tell us at what time the next transition will happen at

**B) Transition Dynamics: (Embedded Discrete Chain) Jump Process** : This is used to determine where the chain will go to next and at what time this transition will happen

For all $m$ states in the Markov Chain, define a set of $m$ holding rates $\lambda_i = \lambda_1, \lambda_2, ... \lambda_m$.

Here, $\lambda_i = \sum_{j} q_{ij}$. For example,  $\lambda_1 = q_{11} + q_{12} + q_{13} + ... + q_{1m}$

If we are currently in state $i$, then the probability distribution of the "time at which the next transition will happen" is said to have the following probability distribution (an Exponential Distribution):

$$f_T(t) = \lambda_i e^{-\lambda_i t}$$

And if we are current in state $i$, the probability of transitioning to any other state is given by (note that this $P_{ij}$ is time INDEPENDENT - this is the Jump Process):

$$P_{ij} = \frac{q_{ij}}{\sum_{j} q_{ij}}$$

Here, $q_{ij}$ itself is the **average transition rate** (across all small time intervals) over all possible times between states (i,j). Thus, $P_{ij}$ can be thought of as the average of the average transition rate between (i,j) across all possible times (i.e. time independent transition probability).

**This is where my confusion begins:** For the same Markov Chain, how can we have a "time independent" transition probability $P_{ij}(t)$ AND a "time dependent" transition probability $P_{ij}$ at the same time? **Why is there no direct relationship between $P_{ij}(t)$ and $P_{ij}$** ?

To me, the only way this can make sense if there was some "limit" relationship between  $P_{ij}(t)$ and $P_{ij}$, or some integral relationship that would suggest $P_{ij}$ is the **average transition probability** from state i to state j across all possible times.

I tried to represent this idea with the following equations (I think they are all wrong):

$$P_{ij} = \int_0^\infty  \lambda_i e^{-\lambda_i t} P_{ij}(t) dt = \frac{q_{ij}}{\sum_{j} q_{ij}}$$

$$\lim_{{t \to 0}} P_{ij}(t) = P_{ij} = \frac{q_{ij}}{\sum_{j} q_{ij}}$$

$$E[P_{ij}(t)] = P_{ij} = \frac{q_{ij}}{\sum_{j} q_{ij}}$$

$$\frac{1}{\Delta t}\int_{0}^{\Delta t} P_{ij}(t) dt = P_{ij} = \frac{q_{ij}}{\sum_{j} q_{ij}}$$

**Can someone please help me understand this?** **Why is there no direct relationship between $P_{ij}(t)$ and $P_{ij}$** ?

Thanks!

- Note: If there are 3 states and you are currently in state 1 - generate a random number from an exponential distribution with $\lambda_2$ and a random number from an exponential distribution with $\lambda_3$ : the smaller of these times will be the transition time (and it will tell you which state you go to next)
- Note: The Taylor series expansion for the exponential function is given by (I think the Pade Approximation can be used here for faster convergence but I am not sure how to write it):

$$e^x = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{x^n}{n!}$$

$$e^{tQ} = I + tQ + \frac{(tQ)^2}{2!} + \frac{(tQ)^3}{3!} + \frac{(tQ)^4}{4!} + \cdots$$

- Note: $\frac{dP_{ij}(t)}{dt} = \sum_{k \neq j} P_{ik}(t)q_{kj} - P_{ij}(t)q_{j}$ is equivalent to $\frac{dP(t)}{dt} = P(t)Q$

Answer (score 1):

**Disclaimer**

Not a full answer, but too long to be a comment.

**Time (in)Dependence**

In the context of Continuous Time Markov Chain, the process changes state at a random time, and the new state it changes into is also random. Therefore there are two typical questions:

1. When the process finally changes from state $i$, what is the probability that it changes into state $j$?
2. If the initial state is $i$, what is the probability that the state becomes $j$ after certain time $t$?

The first is specified by the time independent $P_{i,j}$ in your post.

The second is specified by the time dependent $P(t)$ in your post.

**Relation Between The Two**

I am no expert in the field but I guess the relation is quite complex. For example, for a large $t$ the process may change state several times or none at all. And in theory, there are countless state combinations within a duration $t$