# Relationship between Eigenvalues and Markov Chains

Tags: linear-algebra, probability

**I am trying to understand the relationship between Eigenvalues (Linear Algebra) and Markov Chains (Probability).** Particularly, these two concepts (i.e. Eigenvalues and Markov Chains) seem to have a very natural relationship - but I have never been able to understand why this is.

I will first write my understanding of these concepts:

1. **Eigenvalues**

Let us define the following:

$$Av = \lambda v$$

- $A$ is an $m$ x $m$ matrix
- $I$ is the identity matrix of same dimensions as $A$
- $v$ is an eigenvector (non-zero vector)
- $λ$ is the corresponding eigenvalue (scalar)

If we set the determinant of $(A - λI)$ equal to zero and solve for $λ$. This is called the characteristic equation of $A$:

$$det(A - λI) = 0$$

The solutions to this equation are the eigenvalues of $A$

2. **Markov Chains**

- For an $m$ state **Discrete Time Markov Chain**, we can write its Transition Matrix as (the probability of transitioning from any state $i$ to state $j$):

$$
P_{i,j} = 
\begin{bmatrix}
p_{11} & p_{12} & \cdots & p_{1m} \\
p_{21} & p_{22} & \cdots & p_{2m} \\
\vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
p_{m1} & p_{m2} & \cdots & p_{mm}
\end{bmatrix}
$$

At time=0, we define a vector of "initial probabilities" that shows the probability of the Markov Chain being in any of its states:

$$
\pi_0 = [\pi_1, \pi_2, ..., \pi_m]
$$

Using the Chapman-Kolmogorov equation, we find out the probability of being in any given state at any given time:

$$\pi(t) = \pi_0 \cdot P^t$$

Note that Chapman-Kolmogorov allows for the following (convenient) relationship to be true:  $P^{m+n} = P^m * P^n$

**3) Solving the Stationary Distribution of a Markov Chain:**

In general, we consider the Stationary Distribution $\pi$ as the "long term probabilities" (i.e. after $n$ steps) that the Markov Chain will be in any of its given states:

$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \pi_0 P^n = \pi$$

In other words, if we have ANY state distribution vector - after a certain amount of time, we are guaranteed to end up in the same state distribution vector. This is the Stationary Distribution. All possible state distribution vectors eventually lead to the Stationary Distribution.

Another way to think about it - if you multiply some state distribution vector by the transition matrix ... and the result of this multiplication is the same state distribution: this state distribution vector is the Stationary Distribution:

$$\begin{align*}
\pi_1 &= \pi_0 \cdot P \\
\pi_2 &= \pi_1 \cdot P \\
\pi_3 &= \pi_2 \cdot P \\
&\vdots \\
\pi_n &= \pi_{n-1} \cdot P
\end{align*}$$

For some large $n$, when $\pi_{n-1}$ approximately equals $\pi_{n}$, we get: $\pi = \pi P$

To solve for $\pi$, we can do:

$$\pi P = \pi$$

$$\begin{bmatrix}
\pi_1 & \pi_2 & \cdots & \pi_m
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
p_{11} & p_{12} & \cdots & p_{1m} \\
p_{21} & p_{22} & \cdots & p_{2m} \\
\vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
p_{m1} & p_{m2} & \cdots & p_{mm}
\end{bmatrix}
=
\begin{bmatrix}
\pi_1 & \pi_2 & \cdots & \pi_m
\end{bmatrix}$$

$$\sum_{i=1}^{m} \pi_i = 1$$

**My Question:** Solving the above just seems to be the same as solving a linear system of equations. I don't directly see any relationships to Eigenvalues and Eigenvectors.

Here is an idea:

If $\lambda =1$, then $Av = \lambda v$ becomes $Av =  v$

If we take the transpose of the Stationary Distribution $\pi P = \pi$, then $\pi^T = (\pi P)^T = P^T \pi^T $.

Thus, $Av =  v$ is similar to $\pi^T = P^T \pi^T $ . This suggests that $\pi$ is an eigenvector of the matrix $P$ (for an eigenvalue of $\lambda=1$).

Is this the correct interpretation?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

**Why Eigenanalysis**

Let each column of a matrix $\mathbf{V}$ be an eigenvector of $\mathbf{P}^{\top}$ and each diagonal in a diagonal matrix $\mathbf{D}$ be the associated eigenvalues. The following holds:

$$
\mathbf{P}^{\top}=\mathbf{V}\mathbf{D}\mathbf{V}^{-1}
$$

or

$$
\mathbf{P}=\mathbf{V}^{-\top}\mathbf{D}\mathbf{V}^{\top}
$$

This form is ubiquitous in the field where repeated matrix multiplication is present, one such field be the Markov chain. This is the case because:

$$
\mathbf{P}^{m}=\mathbf{V}^{-\top}\mathbf{D}^{m}\mathbf{V}^{\top}
$$

Since $\mathbf{D}$ is a diagonal matrix, $\mathbf{D}^{m}$ is simply the same matrix with each of its diagonal entry raised to the power of $m$. Plain and simple to compute.

**Stationary Distribution**

Just like you mentioned, the stationary distribution is simply a linear combinations of eigenvectors associated with eigenvalue equals to one.

Comment: thank you so much for your answer! I will read it in close detail in the morning. Do you have any ideas about this question? https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4849093/taking-the-limits-of-probabilities thank you so much!